# QGIS - list with clear name colours

Tags: qgis, symbology, expression, color

One may use data defined override in order to set symbol colours. The expression editor says, the expected format would be

> string [r,g,b,a] as int 0-255 or #AARRGGBB as hex or color as color's name

For lazy coding with few colours the last approach is the easiest (in my opinion). Still, I was wondering if there's an exhaustive list of the colours accepted as arguments? I looked through the official documentation and googled some, but probably didn't use the correct terms.

Can someone provide me with said list of colour names?

Comment: Fyi for others, the rgba format is something like: to_string(to_int( "RedFloat")) + ',' + to_string(to_int("GreenFloat")) + ',' + to_string(to_int("BlueFloat")) + ',255'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QGIS uses Qt for its graphical rendering (among other things). https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcolor.html#setNamedColor points to https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#ColorKeywords so I expect that to be a comprehensive list of all the supported colors.

| colour name | RGB code |
| --- | --- |
| aliceblue | rgb(240, 248, 255) |
| antiquewhite | rgb(250, 235, 215) |
| aqua | rgb( 0, 255, 255) |
| aquamarine | rgb(127, 255, 212) |
| azure | rgb(240, 255, 255) |
| beige | rgb(245, 245, 220) |
| bisque | rgb(255, 228, 196) |
| black | rgb( 0, 0, 0) |
| blanchedalmond | rgb(255, 235, 205) |
| blue | rgb( 0, 0, 255) |
| blueviolet | rgb(138, 43, 226) |
| brown | rgb(165, 42, 42) |
| burlywood | rgb(222, 184, 135) |
| cadetblue | rgb( 95, 158, 160) |
| chartreuse | rgb(127, 255, 0) |
| chocolate | rgb(210, 105, 30) |
| coral | rgb(255, 127, 80) |
| cornflowerblue | rgb(100, 149, 237) |
| cornsilk | rgb(255, 248, 220) |
| crimson | rgb(220, 20, 60) |
| cyan | rgb( 0, 255, 255) |
| darkblue | rgb( 0, 0, 139) |
| darkcyan | rgb( 0, 139, 139) |
| darkgoldenrod | rgb(184, 134, 11) |
| darkgray | rgb(169, 169, 169) |
| darkgreen | rgb( 0, 100, 0) |
| darkgrey | rgb(169, 169, 169) |
| darkkhaki | rgb(189, 183, 107) |
| darkmagenta | rgb(139, 0, 139) |
| darkolivegreen | rgb( 85, 107, 47) |
| darkorange | rgb(255, 140, 0) |
| darkorchid | rgb(153, 50, 204) |
| darkred | rgb(139, 0, 0) |
| darksalmon | rgb(233, 150, 122) |
| darkseagreen | rgb(143, 188, 143) |
| darkslateblue | rgb( 72, 61, 139) |
| darkslategray | rgb( 47, 79, 79) |
| darkslategrey | rgb( 47, 79, 79) |
| darkturquoise | rgb( 0, 206, 209) |
| darkviolet | rgb(148, 0, 211) |
| deeppink | rgb(255, 20, 147) |
| deepskyblue | rgb( 0, 191, 255) |
| dimgray | rgb(105, 105, 105) |
| dimgrey | rgb(105, 105, 105) |
| dodgerblue | rgb( 30, 144, 255) |
| firebrick | rgb(178, 34, 34) |
| floralwhite | rgb(255, 250, 240) |
| forestgreen | rgb( 34, 139, 34) |
| fuchsia | rgb(255, 0, 255) |
| gainsboro | rgb(220, 220, 220) |
| ghostwhite | rgb(248, 248, 255) |
| gold | rgb(255, 215, 0) |
| goldenrod | rgb(218, 165, 32) |
| gray | rgb(128, 128, 128) |
| grey | rgb(128, 128, 128) |
| green | rgb( 0, 128, 0) |
| greenyellow | rgb(173, 255, 47) |
| honeydew | rgb(240, 255, 240) |
| hotpink | rgb(255, 105, 180) |
| indianred | rgb(205, 92, 92) |
| indigo | rgb( 75, 0, 130) |
| ivory | rgb(255, 255, 240) |
| khaki | rgb(240, 230, 140) |
| lavender | rgb(230, 230, 250) |
| lavenderblush | rgb(255, 240, 245) |
| lawngreen | rgb(124, 252, 0) |
| lemonchiffon | rgb(255, 250, 205) |
| lightblue | rgb(173, 216, 230) |
| lightcoral | rgb(240, 128, 128) |
| lightcyan | rgb(224, 255, 255) |
| lightgoldenrodyellow | rgb(250, 250, 210) |
| lightgray | rgb(211, 211, 211) |
| lightgreen | rgb(144, 238, 144) |
| lightgrey | rgb(211, 211, 211) |
| lightpink | rgb(255, 182, 193) |
| lightsalmon | rgb(255, 160, 122) |
| lightseagreen | rgb( 32, 178, 170) |
| lightskyblue | rgb(135, 206, 250) |
| lightslategray | rgb(119, 136, 153) |
| lightslategrey | rgb(119, 136, 153) |
| lightsteelblue | rgb(176, 196, 222) |
| lightyellow | rgb(255, 255, 224) |
| lime | rgb( 0, 255, 0) |
| limegreen | rgb( 50, 205, 50) |
| linen | rgb(250, 240, 230) |
| magenta | rgb(255, 0, 255) |
| maroon | rgb(128, 0, 0) |
| mediumaquamarine | rgb(102, 205, 170) |
| mediumblue | rgb( 0, 0, 205) |
| mediumorchid | rgb(186, 85, 211) |
| mediumpurple | rgb(147, 112, 219) |
| mediumseagreen | rgb( 60, 179, 113) |
| mediumslateblue | rgb(123, 104, 238) |
| mediumspringgreen | rgb( 0, 250, 154) |
| mediumturquoise | rgb( 72, 209, 204) |
| mediumvioletred | rgb(199, 21, 133) |
| midnightblue | rgb( 25, 25, 112) |
| mintcream | rgb(245, 255, 250) |
| mistyrose | rgb(255, 228, 225) |
| moccasin | rgb(255, 228, 181) |
| navajowhite | rgb(255, 222, 173) |
| navy | rgb( 0, 0, 128) |
| oldlace | rgb(253, 245, 230) |
| olive | rgb(128, 128, 0) |
| olivedrab | rgb(107, 142, 35) |
| orange | rgb(255, 165, 0) |
| orangered | rgb(255, 69, 0) |
| orchid | rgb(218, 112, 214) |
| palegoldenrod | rgb(238, 232, 170) |
| palegreen | rgb(152, 251, 152) |
| paleturquoise | rgb(175, 238, 238) |
| palevioletred | rgb(219, 112, 147) |
| papayawhip | rgb(255, 239, 213) |
| peachpuff | rgb(255, 218, 185) |
| peru | rgb(205, 133, 63) |
| pink | rgb(255, 192, 203) |
| plum | rgb(221, 160, 221) |
| powderblue | rgb(176, 224, 230) |
| purple | rgb(128, 0, 128) |
| red | rgb(255, 0, 0) |
| rosybrown | rgb(188, 143, 143) |
| royalblue | rgb( 65, 105, 225) |
| saddlebrown | rgb(139, 69, 19) |
| salmon | rgb(250, 128, 114) |
| sandybrown | rgb(244, 164, 96) |
| seagreen | rgb( 46, 139, 87) |
| seashell | rgb(255, 245, 238) |
| sienna | rgb(160, 82, 45) |
| silver | rgb(192, 192, 192) |
| skyblue | rgb(135, 206, 235) |
| slateblue | rgb(106, 90, 205) |
| slategray | rgb(112, 128, 144) |
| slategrey | rgb(112, 128, 144) |
| snow | rgb(255, 250, 250) |
| springgreen | rgb( 0, 255, 127) |
| steelblue | rgb( 70, 130, 180) |
| tan | rgb(210, 180, 140) |
| teal | rgb( 0, 128, 128) |
| thistle | rgb(216, 191, 216) |
| tomato | rgb(255, 99, 71) |
| turquoise | rgb( 64, 224, 208) |
| violet | rgb(238, 130, 238) |
| wheat | rgb(245, 222, 179) |
| white | rgb(255, 255, 255) |
| whitesmoke | rgb(245, 245, 245) |
| yellow | rgb(255, 255, 0) |
| yellowgreen | rgb(154, 205, 50) |

Comment: It would be great if the QGIS documentation was clear about this, maybe you could file a feature request at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/ for it? :)

Comment: @Erik You copied the whole table into my answer. I don't think that is a good idea as the linked page is a highly reputable and stable resource. Anyways, if you want it this way, you must include the appropriate licensing information. Please add that. For reference: https://www.w3.org/Consortium/Legal/2015/doc-license